# getTile() returns nothing in native map types, how to get back functionality?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

On an early version of the maps 3 api, I build some "overlay" functionality to do the following using a custom map type - the idea was that as opposed to always serving my tiles on top of google's tiles, I would only show google's tiles when needed - that is either when the tile is outside of my zoom and boundaries or when my tile has transparency (mostly due to the fact that the outside borders of my overlays may follow rivers, etc). It worked like so:

1. When `getTile` was called on my type, determine if I should be serving the given tile for the given level.
2. If I should be serving the tile, determine if the tile had any transparency - if it did, get the tile from the default map using

   ```
   map.mapTypes.get(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP).getTile(coord, zoom, ownerDocument)`
   ```

   then append my image to the top of the returned div and display that. Otherwise, just serve my tile.
3. If I should not be serving, the tile, just return

   ```
   map.mapTypes.get(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP).getTile(coord, zoom, ownerDocument)
   ```

So, it seems like due to some thievery, getTile no longer returns anything on google's native map types, which bring up two questions:

1. Is there any way for me to tell the map that it should be displaying my tile as an overlay as opposed to a full tile without having to have my whole map be an overlay?
2. Is there any way to tell the map that it should be displaying its own tile as opposed to mine?

---

The overlay maps work as a solution, but performance is not great, there are quite a few redraws as google first draws its own tiles and then overlays them with mine. Since 99% of my tiles are a complete overlay (no transparency) this seems like quite a waste of bandwidth. It would be great to be able to pass back metadata from getTile indicating whether the default google tile should be drawn at all  (or indicate that fact in some other callback). What I had previously seemed like an elegant solution and performed well - the overlay methodology is definitely a step back. Marcelo, I'm not sure how my title does not reflect my question... did you read the complete text of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the base map types. It's been intentionally disabled by Google due to ongoing abuse.

At some point this was reported as a bug, but you can read the comments by members of the maps team on [**this thread**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3635#c2):

Quote from that page:

> Unfortunately we discovered an increasing number of cases of developrs
> using the default map types to gain access to and use Google map tiles
> outside of a google.maps.Map object, which is not permitted by the
> Terms of Service. We were therefore forced to move the internal map
> types to a private registry. If you have specific reasons for needing
> access to the map types that are compliant with the Terms of Service,
> please update this issue with your use case, and if there is
> sufficient demand we will look into whether we can provide a
> supportable solution for your requirements.

by Thor Mitchell (Google Employee - Maps Team)

Comment: Thor, thanks very much - I understand that the getTile() function now returns nothing for native maps, I was simply asking if there is a solution that will allow me to place one of my tiles (with transparency) directly over a google tile and a solution that will allow me to prompt google to display a tile when I do not want to display a custom tile...

Comment: Then edit your question to reflect that, (especially the title).